# How to query with the ID of the parent instance using **kwargs in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am currently implementing soft deletion for all models in my database. The idea is that when an instance gets deleted, it actually gets archived with all of its children. If the user tries to create an instance that is identical to the archived one, the archived one gets undeleted along with all of its children instead of creating a new instance.

To do this, I am using django-safedelete where I am making a BaseModel with an overwritten save() method that looks something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # get the foreign key id
    foreign_key_id = self.foreign_field.id

    # execute a query by that id and some other params
    '''I don't know how to do this'''
```

As to how to do it, I thought I could construct a kwargs dictionary that consists of pairs of  <field>:value where <field> = self._meta.get_field(some_field.name) and value = getattr(self, some_field.name).

So how do I add the foreign_key_id to kwargs? I know there is this syntax: `Model.objects.filter(foreign_field__id=value)`

...but I don't know how to replicate that to put into kwargs the way I'm doing it.

Likewise, is there a better way to do this in general? I don't want to hard-code too many things, which is why I didn't just do this individually for each of the models that I have.

Thank you so much in advance.